# Appending to the output of Powershell script

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script that would create a sql file with a list of file names within a given directory appended by a PRINT statement and ":r" command at the beginning of each filename and finished by "GO" at the end of the filename.

Please see below.

```
PRINT 'C:/Schemas/Admin.sql'
GO
:r "C:/Schemas/Admin.sql"
GO
PRINT 'C:/Schemas/Audit.sql'
GO
:r "C:/Schemas/Audit.sql"
GO
```

I am able to print out the file names, but I can't seem to figure out how to prefix and suffix each line.
This is what I have:

```
(get-childitem "C:\schemas" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".sql"}).fullname | out-file "C:\powerShell\masterSQL.sql"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you can make it show in the console the way you want, then you can either capture to a variable or pipe straight out as the same format. A couple of improvements can be made.

First, do the filtering on the `Get-ChildItem` command itself, letting the filesystem provider to the heavy lifting. Much faster than getting all files and filtering with `Where-Object`

Second, use `Set-Content` so you don't end up with weird or otherwise unexpected encoding issues.

Last thing to note is the doubled up double quotes around the `$_` (the fullname) this is to ensure the path is surrounded with double quotes.

```
(Get-ChildItem "C:\schemas" -Filter *.sql -Recurse).FullName |
        ForEach-Object {
            "PRINT ""$_"""
            "GO"
            ":r ""$_"""
            "GO"
        } | Set-Content -Path "C:\powerShell\masterSQL.sql" -Encoding UTF8
```